# help with xpath selecting

Tags: php, xml

i've got an id attribute value for an element.

i want to select only its children (not all descendants).

i used

```
$childElements = $xml->xpath('//entity[@id=212323]');
print_r($childElements);
```

but that would select ALL descendants and print them out. i just want to select the 1 generation children. how could i do that?

```
<entity id=212323>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
    </this>
</entity>
```

(cause the hierarchy is very long, so fecthing all descendants would slow the process down, and its not smart to fetch unnecessary data).

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but this might me a step in the right direction: `//entity[@id=212323]/child::*/text()` or maybe `//entity[@id=212323]/child::*/child::text()`

Comment: no it still fetched every element under the id element.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. When you print an element, you're printing it, and all its children, right?  Even if you only select the top-level children, if you print them... you print everything.  you need to rethink your requirements.

Comment: so how could i loop though only the children of that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this:

```
//entity[@id=212323]/child::*[not(boolean(child::*))]
```

to select only the nodes which don't have children. If this is not good enough and you expect also cases like:

```
<entity id=212323>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>asd</this>
    <this>
        text node 1
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
        <notThis>asd</notThis>
        text node 2
    </this>
</entity>
```

You should do some more research. In this example `text node 1` and `text node 2` are considered as children of `<this>` element. You need to find out (I am not sure if it is possible) how to differ this two nodes from the others(like `<notThis>asd</notThis>`) in your xPath expression.